# Change default copy renaming in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer

I am trying to enable the solution to this question to work in Windows 7 but so far with out luck:

[Any option to change Windows XP default Copy Here naming from "Copy of {name}.{ext}" to "{name}.{ext}.copy"](https://superuser.com/questions/118351/any-option-to-change-windows-xp-default-copy-here-naming-from-copy-of-name-e)

I tried by creating the .cmd file, but did not achieve exactly what I wanted to.

My basic question is suppose there is a file, xxx.ext already in a folder. When I copy to the the same folder, a file with the same name, it is named as xxx(1).ext. I want to name this as xxx_1.ext. Could you please tell me a way for this?

Is there any default setting which I have change somewhere?

Comment: `Send to` is a folder containing links for Windows `Context Menu`. Even if you add it as a `cmd` you need to use `Copy of` from context menu to make it work. Usual `Ctrl+C` & `Ctrl+V` will have same old effects.

Comment: the usual ctrl+c, ctrl+v are naming the files as xxx(1).ext, xxx(2).ext. I wanna name them as xxx_1.ext, xxx_2.ext. @SparKotॐ. Could you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: @Luke : Please read the question clearly and then make comments. I solved a part of the issue. To find the sendTo folder in windows 7. I think the first comment was also clearer. My second part is wat I have elaborated in the end!

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan I've tried to edit the question to clear up what you are asking. I don't believe you can override the built-in Copy/Paste filenaming. The solution in the question you linked to created a cmd file to accomplish the rename behavior and had to be triggered from the Send To menu. Is this what you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly "xxx(1).ext" on Windows 7. "File Name.ext" is copied to "File Name - Copy.ext", then "File Name - Copy (2).ext", "File Name - Copy (3).ext" and so on. Instead you want "File Name.ext" to be copied to "File Name_1.ext", "File Name_2.ext" and so on? The cmd file can be easily modified accordingly:

```
for %%f in (%*) do call :try_copy %%f 1
goto :eof

:try_copy
if not exist "%~n1_%2%~x1" goto :copy
call :try_next %1 %2
goto :eof

:copy
copy %1 "%~n1_%2%~x1"
goto :eof

:try_next
if "%2" == "" ( set _next=1 ) else ( set /a _next=%2 + 1 )
call :try_copy %1 %_next%
goto :eof
```

---

**Edit:** As per discussion below, modified batch file to copy files to a specific folder and rename sequentially:

```
REM Specify your destination path below without quotes or trailing backslash
set folder=I:\New folder

for %%f in (%*) do call :try_copy %%f 1
goto :eof

:try_copy
if not exist "%folder%\%~n1_%2%~x1" goto :copy
call :try_next %1 %2
goto :eof

:copy
copy %1 "%folder%\%~n1_%2%~x1"
goto :eof

:try_next
if "%2" == "" ( set _next=1 ) else ( set /a _next=%2 + 1 )
call :try_copy %1 %_next%
goto :eof
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Karan. Could you please temme wat coding is this? I want to learn this as well. Moreover, after I create the .cmd file, please tell me how exactly I can use it. Thanks in advance again.

Comment: It's a batch file, and there are a gazillion tutorials on the net. As for instructions, refer to the other question you yourself linked to. Basically you just need to place this in your sendto folder.

Comment: The explanation is given in that answer, but I tried it, and it did not work well. So please tell me how exactly I should use that file. Should I use it after copying the items to the folder having the same name?

Comment: Like for eg. I have xxx.ext. I wanna copy files to the folder, so that the next xxx.ext becomes xxx_1.ext. I am slightly confused here. Please help me.

Comment: Please note that xxx.ext and the new xxx.ext are actually 2 different files. I want them both. Since I have like 500 files, I cannot possibly sit and rename them all. That is why I am looking for this option. And I need them all in the same folder. That is why am asking for an explanation please. :).

Comment: Both the original batch file and mine will duplicate files in the *same* folder. If you copy "File Name.ext" in a folder and paste in the *same* folder, it will be duplicated as "File Name - Copy.ext", "File Name - Copy (2).ext" and so on. If you are trying to copy from one folder to another and "File Name.ext" already exists, you will see the [following dialog](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uaLo0.png) which will allow you to create "File Name (2).ext", "File Name (3).ext" and so on. This cannot be overridden unless you use a shell extension that overrides Windows' default naming convention.

Comment: What is your problem exactly? I think there might be a better solution than what you have asked for above. You have 500 files with the exact same name but different content, and want to copy them all to the same directory? Is that it?

Comment: Is it possible to add a path in that code, and when I select the files to be sent to the folder, if there are files with the same name existing, it will automatically be names as xxx_1.ext?

Comment: I guess so, but then it won't be a general solution. You would have to go and edit the CMD every time that path changes. Can you answer my query above regarding your actual problem?

Comment: Yes. I have some 500 files, which have the same name, and I want to incorporate them all in a folder. But when I copy, the name changes to xxx(2).ext. Am running a software in linux on this folder, and it is not able to read the filename with '(', as it throws error.

Comment: Yes I don't want a general solution. Just for that folder right now is enuf for me. Please tell me if it possible. If so, kindly help me.

Comment: Can I suggest a simple solution? Just copy all the files with (1), (2) in their names, then use a bulk file renamer such as [this one](http://www.den4b.com/?x=products&product=renamer) or [this one](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php) (there are many more) to rename all the files in the format you prefer i.e. "File Name_n.ext"

Comment: That is the problem here. Sitting and selecting all those files with that name alone, since they are in between and not continuous. That is why I resorted for this solution. I thot of bulk rename as well. But it is a bit tedious to sit and select.Its almost the same as selecting and renaming. Could you please tell me the way to code the way I thot? :).

Comment: Yes, I can try and edit the code and test and edit my answer, but if there's an easier way it's always preferable compared to fiddling with batch files. :) Since all files have the same name, why can't you simply search for that file name in Win Explorer, then copy all together and paste in one folder? Windows will ask you to rename, and you can select the "Do this action for all files" checkbox so all files will be renamed sequentially with (1), (2) etc. Then once all the files are there in a single dir, it'll take a few secs. to bulk rename them.

Comment: I think it is not possible like that. If I select all the files with '(', and try to rename them, they produce another set of paranthesis, as they are all having the same name. Please understand that wen I sid 500 files are having the same name, I meant like 3 files are of name xxx.ext, 4 files aaa.ext, and so on. That is why I was saying its tedious :).

Comment: I am sorry if I wasn't clear earlier. Apologies.

Comment: For the record, I'm not sure what Linux utility you're using, but no decent program should have any problems at all with a simple thing like a bracket in a filename. Perhaps you're calling it incorrectly... The first question I would probably have asked in this situation would have been - how can I get these filenames with brackets recognised by this Linux utility? That would have been tackling the problem at its source, instead of this long drawn out round-about method. Anyway... I'll see what I can do, give me some time. :)

Comment: Sure thanks a lot :). It is actually called Bundler, a computer vision program, to actually perform some correction on 3d points of images. The folder is full of images. When I tried, it threw me an error stating these braces as the reason. That is why I thot of renaming it this way. Thanks for your time :).