# Change Default Naming Behavior When Copying Files - Making Revision Versions

Tags: windows, copy-paste, cmd.exe, filenames, send-to

In Windows 7, when I copy/paste a file named "project.ext" I want the result to be "project Rev.1.ext". ([That part is solved by tweaking the code in this post.](https://superuser.com/questions/118351/any-option-to-change-windows-xp-default-copy-here-naming-from-copy-of-name-e)) In addition to that, however, I want subsequent copies to be named "project Rev.2.ext", "project Rev.3.ext", etc. (NOT "project Rev.1.Rev.1.ext") This requires somehow recognizing when a file name is already a revision.

I'm basically trying to avoid the minor-yet-nearly-constant hassle of manually renaming every revised file I create.

Comment: To be clear, I will not be making multiple copies of one file. Rather, if "Project.ext" requires changes, I copy the original, update the name with "Rev.1" and make the changes. When subsequent changes are required, I copy the "Rev.1" file and update the name to "Rev.2" before making the new changes. This continues until the file is approved. I need to retain all iterations.