# Changing the filename given automatically to copied files

Tags: windows-7, windows

If one copies a file from one directory into the same one, Windows will append a `- Copy` to the file (well, technically `- Kopie`, since I have a German install, but you get it).

Is there a way to change that behaviour, as in change the suffix of the new file (perhaps even to the current date)?

(Note that I would like a way to do it directly [via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> ] instead of having to right click on the file to copy the way it is shown in the similar question.)

Comment: While I understand why this is marked as a duplicate, I don't agree. This doesn't completely answer the question whether there is a way to do it "properly", it only shows a workaround. (Which is *something*, but inconvenient.)

Answer (score -1):

There is a workaround in which they leverage the "Send to" shell menu.

Basically the core of the solution in a batch file so you will be able to use the date/time

Check it out [here](https://superuser.com/questions/118351/any-option-to-change-windows-xp-default-copy-here-naming-from-copy-of-name-e)