# How to change context menu option for 7zip?

Tags: compression, 7-zip

I work a lot with .gzip format and I am wondering if there is a way to change the default "Add to" format in the context from .zip to .gzip.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happened to .gzip option in 7-zip?](http://superuser.com/questions/952653/what-happened-to-gzip-option-in-7-zip)

Comment: @Moab - thanks for pointing it out but it's not a duplicate. I actually asked both questions but they are separate issues.

Comment: See [How to add a Windows Explorer context menu item with custom functionality?](https://superuser.com/q/65105/116475)