# What happened to .gzip option in 7-zip?

Tags: compression, 7-zip

I am not sure if this is just a coincident or not but I have recently upgraded my OS to Win 10.

I noticed only now (after the upgrade) that the .gzip archive format is not available in 7-zip anymore.

Perhaps I am missing something. But is there a way to archive a file/directory in a .gzip format in Win10?

If so, could anyone please advise where/how to select the .gzip option?

Thanks!

[image]

**Edit**:

I tested 7-zip on Win 7 and also I tried to gzip .txt file and a .tar file in Win10.

Here are my findings:

I can gzip a .txt file in Win 7.

[image: win7]

I can also gzip a .tar file in Win 10 but I can't gzip a .txt file in Win 10.
This option is no longer available in Win 10.

[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You cannot gzip multiple files. Create a tar file first then gzip.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running 15.0.5 beta, on Windows 10 x64, and I definitely have gzip as an option. (See below.)

I'd reinstall using the latest package.

[image]

Comment: I did reinstall 7-zip running the same version as you 7-zip 15.05 beta x64 but I still have no gzip option.